# Making a server-sided "localhost" API call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

In Javascript, it is possible to load server-sided files via HTML or Javascript. I am trying to do the same thing except via an API call instead of a file directly (as this file is automatically generated).

I'm hosting a `flask` server that's being served to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` on a remote linux server, and I am able to make a `GET` request on the server via command line using `wget http://localhost:5000/data` and it will return the correct result.

However, if I try to make an `ajax` call on an `html` page it instead tries to `GET` data from my local computer's `localhost` rather than the server's `localhost`

For example, I have a simple `index.html` on the server, served by `nginx`:

```
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data"
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to call on the server's localhost, and instead calls on the localhost of my computer. (i.e. it returns the results only if I am running the API service locally as well, and `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` otherwise). How can I make it call on the "server"s localhost? Is this even possible to do?

An obvious workaround would be to process the file on the server and then save it to disk, and then call on the file directly via `ajax`, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: use the lan ip address instead of the loopback address

Comment: Thats because localhost is your computer only, it translates to the loopback adapter or 127.0.0.1. You need to use the hostname or ip of the server, not localhost.

Comment: `localhost` by definition isn't remote; if you are requesting something from `localhost:5000`, you're talking to a web server on your own machine, not a remote one. Also, you cannot request a resource using AJAX from another server unless the server specifically sets CORS headers to allow it.

Comment: @ChrisWatts what if port 5000 of the server is not publically accessible? I tried for using ajax on `http://142.103.37.154:5000/data` but I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. 

However, `curl http://142.103.37.154:5000/data` is working properly on the command line of the remote server.


Serving my flask app on `http://142.103.37.154:5000` doesn't alleviate this error

Comment: 1. Use the public IP address of your server. 2. Check that this port is accessible from external source. check that the firewall isn't blocking connections on that port on your sever. If it is then you will have to enable this port on your server.

Comment: @Legacy if you run the curl command on the remote server, instead of using the IP address (and going out to the router/switch and back), the traffic will actually be directed to the loopback connector on the server. As Paul Okeke mentioned, you need to check the firewall on the server you are running the application on.

Comment: @PaulOkeke The port is not publically accessible, but is accessible from the "inside". However, since my app is hosted on the remote server, the app (but not my browser) should theoretically have access to the port. How can I tell my HTML file to make the call from the server?

Comment: @Legacy hmmm.. you seem to have some confused understandings.. When you open the app on your browser. All your static files are downloaded to the localsystem: hence its best you see it has your browser making the request to your server.. theoretically you need to enable the port to receive public request